One to one relationship crashes when trying to intialize
@Model
class Habit: Identifiable {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: UUID = UUID()
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) var completedDays: CompletedDays?
    var name: String = ""
    var color: String = ""
    
    init(completedDays: CompletedDays? = nil, name: String, color: String) {
        self.completedDays = completedDays
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
    }
}

@Model
class CompletedDays {
    @Relationship(inverse: \Habit.completedDays) var habit: Habit?
    var days: [Int: [Int: [Int]]] = [:]
    
    init(habit: Habit? = nil) {
        self.habit = habit
    }
}

In my application each habit has a completedDays dictionary like this: [years[months[days]]]. You can tap a day and it gets highlighted. This dictionary contains all the dates that have been highlighted.
A friend of mine suggested separating the completedDays dictionary from the Habit model. That way I can load the names and colors of the habits without having to load all their completedDays dictionaries into memory at the same time.
So I tried separating it out into it's own model called CompletedDays with a days dictionary. That way I can do this: @Query var listHabits: [Habit], which I'm hoping won't load all the completedDays dicts into memory, only references to them.
But if I try to initialize a new Habit using the method below the app crashes.
// create new habit
let name = "test"
let color = "8cb6fa"
let habit = Habit(name: name, color: color)
let completedDays = CompletedDays(habit: habit)
print("The app should crash now...")
habit.completedDays = completedDays // <- it crashes if I add this line, no crash if I remove this line
dbContext.insert(habit)
print("If you made it here the app didn't crash")

When it crashes XCode inserts some extra code into my workspace with this error:
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x2355876b0)
@Model
class Habit: Identifiable {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: UUID = UUID()
    // Relationship to CompletedDays, with cascade delete rule.
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) var completedDays: CompletedDays?
__________________________________________________________________________

{
    // Relationship to CompletedDays, with cascade delete rule.
          @storageRestrictions(accesses: _$backingData, initializes: _completedDays)
        init(initialValue) {
            _$backingData.setValue(forKey: \.completedDays, to: initialValue)
            _completedDays = _SwiftDataNoType()
        }

    // Relationship to CompletedDays, with cascade delete rule.
          get {
            _$observationRegistrar.access(self, keyPath: \.completedDays)
            return self.getValue(forKey: \.completedDays)
        }

    // Relationship to CompletedDays, with cascade delete rule.
          set {
            _$observationRegistrar.withMutation(of: self, keyPath: \.completedDays) {
                self.setValue(forKey: \.completedDays, to: newValue) // <- Error: Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x2355876b0)
            }
        }
}
__________________________________________________________________________


I've tried setting up this relationship in a variety of ways now but I always run into some kind of error related to a circular dependency. My attempt to fix the circular dependancy was to make the CompletedDays and the Habit optional with a default value of nil in both models based on the info I found below. But I'm still facing the error above.
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftdata/how-to-create-one-to-one-relationships
Am I going about this the completely wrong way, or does this setup make sense for my goal?
I've created an MRE below:
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@main
struct TestApplication: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TestView()
                .modelContainer(for: [Habit.self, CompletedDays.self], inMemory: true)
        }
    }
}

@Model
class Habit: Identifiable {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: UUID = UUID()
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) var completedDays: CompletedDays?
    var name: String = ""
    var color: String = ""
    
    init(completedDays: CompletedDays? = nil, name: String, color: String) {
        self.completedDays = completedDays
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        // I tried this as well, but I get an error even if I set completedDays to nil first
        // self.completedDays = CompletedDays(habit: self)
    }
}

@Model
class CompletedDays {
    @Relationship(inverse: \Habit.completedDays) var habit: Habit?
    var days: [Int: [Int: [Int]]] = [:]
    
    init(habit: Habit? = nil) {
        self.habit = habit
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var dbContext
    @State private var habitNameInput: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Tap save and the app should crash")
                .font(.subheadline)
                .padding()
            saveButton()
        }
        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 40)
    }

    func storeHabit() {
        let name = "test"
        let color = "8cb6fa"
        let habit = Habit(name: name, color: color)
        let completedDays = CompletedDays(habit: habit)
        print("The app should crash now...")
        habit.completedDays = completedDays // <- it crashes if I add this line, no crash if I remove this line
        dbContext.insert(habit)
        print("If you made it here the app didn't crash")
    }

    func saveButton() -> some View {
        Button {
            storeHabit()
        } label: {
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
                    .stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 1)
                Text("Save")
            }
            .frame(width: 80, height:40)
        }
    }
}



Why do you have a one-to-one relationship to a model that contains only a collection property when you can have a one-to-many relationship?

As for the crash, try moving the line dbContext.insert(habit) up so it is executed directly after you create the habit object and before you create the other object and see if that helps.

@Purp, the issue is not reproducing for me

@JoakimDanielson executing dbContext.insert(habit) immediately after creating habit does work, thank you. The reason I have one-to-one is because each habit has it's own completedDays dictionary. Or I'm not sure what you mean.

If you have a one-to-many relationship then each habit will have its own collection of CompletedDays objects so in that sense it will not be different.

I got rid of the error by inserting the habit into the database before defining it's completedDays property. I tested it out in the app and it appears to be working.
I'm still not sure if there's a better way to accomplish my goal without using two separate models but the app no longer crashes.
func storeHabit() {
        let name = "test"
        let color = "8cb6fa"
        let habit = Habit(name: name, color: color)
        dbContext.insert(habit) // 1. Insert the habit first
        let completedDays = CompletedDays(habit: habit)
        //dbContext.insert(completedDays) // chatGPT suggested I add this line, but after testing it seems like it's not needed.
        habit.completedDays = completedDays // 2. Now we can define habit.completedDays without crashing
    }

